# How to Separate When updateSearchResultsForSearchController Is Called Due to the Edit or Due to the First Responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

In [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchResultsUpdating_ClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchResultsUpdating/updateSearchResultsForSearchController:) it is written that the method

**-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController**

is called in two cases: when the search bar becomes the first responder or when the user makes changes inside the search bar.

It is possible to resign the first responder with:

```
[complaintSearchController.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

However, is there any possibility to call customMethod only in the cases if the user edits the text in the search bar?

The code is above:

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    [self customMethod];
}
```

Perhaps it is possible to detect the state with any conditional statement:

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
  if (condition){
      [self customMethod];
  }
}
```

For example, `if([complaintSearchController.searchBar isFirstResponder])` does not cover it.

Basically, I need to separate these two cases when this method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I would try an NSNotification that triggers on the protocol UISearchResultsUpdating for your search controller. You can then set that method in your target for the NSNotification.

```
 - (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
    {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"CustomName" object:nil];
      //or potentially you could just call your custom method directly
    }
```

This method is automatically called whenever the search bar becomes the first responder or changes are made to the text in the search bar. Perform any required filtering and updating inside of this method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(customMethod)
                                                 name:@"CustomName"
                                               object:nil];
```

Maybe save the last state of the user input and check if the text has then changed by doing a isEqualToString:

Answer (score 0):

I would add a state in the View Controller:

```
private var vmSearchBarInputDidChange: Bool = false
```

Set this to true in the "-DidChange" UISearchBarDelegate methods, i.e.:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int)
```

Now in the updateSearchResults func, we can:

```
guard vmSearchBarInputDidChange else { return }
```

before doing actual searching.

After performing searching, reset the state before exiting:

```
vmSearchBarInputDidChange = false // reset
```